# How to set background color of TreeView node?

Tags: uwp

We add root nodes to `TreeView` control as below. But how to set background color of that root node. Also set bg-color to any currently selected Item? (I guess, every node is a `TreeViewItem`, But I am unable to retrieve it from nodes)

```
TreeViewNode rootNode1 = new TreeViewNode() {Content = "Flavors"};
sampleTreeView.RootNodes.Add(rootNode1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view), every `TreeViewNode` is a `TreeViewItem` and they use the same `TreeViewItemStyle`. It doesn't expose a method to get TreeViewItem from the Node. But you can modify its style to make it looks different.

You can get the default style of [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) by the following steps:

In the TreeView page, click the **Document Outline** tab, in the **Document Outline** window, you can find your TreeView, then you can create a default style for the treeView as the following image,

[image]

Then click OK to create a copy style, after that, you can see the style in your `Page.Resources`. You can change the style in the resouce to change Nodes' style and the select Node's background.

Here is the default style of the TreeView,

```xml
<Style x:Key="TreeViewStyle1" TargetType="TreeView">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl" AllowDrop="True"
                              CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}">
                    <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <ContentThemeTransition/>
                            <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                            <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                </TreeViewList>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this style, you can see the TreeViewList's `ItemContainerStyle` is using `TreeViewItemStyle` and its `ItemTemplate` is using `TreeViewItemDataTemplate`, you can also find them in this page's resource which is generated from our above steps.

To change Nodes' backgroud, you can modify the `TreeViewItemDataTemplate` as the following code by setting the Grid's Background to Red,

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemDataTemplate">
    <Grid Height="44" Background="Red">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                   Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

To set bg-color to any currently selected Item, you can modify the `TreeViewItemStyle` Selected VisualState,

```
...
    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelected}"/>
            <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushSelected}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
...
```

Moreover, you can also change the Node's background in a row by modifying the `ContentPresenterGrid`'s background.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
```

Comment: Very useful! 'TreeViewItemStyle' has all the stuffs, including the bg color of all items. However, how it could be modified, so that only root nodes' bg colors are different color, so that they will look like a separator/heading.

Comment: <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value = "{Binding Source= Content, Converter={StaticResource MyCustomBg}}"/> I tried with above binding. But unable to get the source, i.e. Content/Text of corresponding Treeview item,  If it is got successfully, this task will be over!

Comment: Actually you should be able to do this with a little bit of work. Please refer to my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the background colour of all items would be to override the `TreeViewItemBackground` `ThemeResource` like this:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackground">Red</SolidColorBrush>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

If you want to change the colour of the selected ones you do the same for the `TreeViewItemBackgroundSelected` resource.

Changing the background colour of the root nodes only requires a bit more effort. You will have to extract the default styles and templates. Once you have done this you could handle the `Loaded` event of the root `Grid` element in the `TreeViewItem`'s `ControlTemplate` and programmatically check whether the `TreeViewItem`'s content has any child nodes. Please refer to the following sample markup.

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView">
    <TreeView.RootNodes>
        <TreeViewNode Content="Root A">
            <TreeViewNode.Children>
                <TreeViewNode Content="a" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="b" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="c" />
            </TreeViewNode.Children>
        </TreeViewNode>
        <TreeViewNode Content="Root B">
            <TreeViewNode.Children>
                <TreeViewNode Content="d" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="e" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="f" />
            </TreeViewNode.Children>
        </TreeViewNode>
    </TreeView.RootNodes>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BaseTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight"/>
            <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="BodyTextBlockStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CaptionTextBlockStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemDataTemplate">
            <Grid Height="44">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
            <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl" AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}">
                <TreeViewList.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                        <Setter Property="GlyphBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForeground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid" 
                                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                  Loaded="ContentPresenterGrid_Loaded">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            ...
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Grid x:Name="MultiSelectGrid">
                                            <Grid.Resources>
                                                <Style x:Name="TreeViewMultiSelectCheckBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundUnchecked}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundUnchecked}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderBrushUnchecked}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="32"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                                                                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="32">
                                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CombinedStates">
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedNormal">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUnchecked}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedPointerOver">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUncheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedPressed">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUncheckedPressed}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedDisabled">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUncheckedDisabled}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedNormal">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBorderSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckGlyphSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBorderSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckGlyphSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBorderSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckGlyphSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"/>
                                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckBoxBorderSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemCheckGlyphSelected}"/>
                                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                    <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillUnchecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckBackgroundStrokeUnchecked}" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                                                                        <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUnchecked}" FontSize="20" Glyph="&#xE001;" Opacity="0"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Grid.Resources>
                                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{Binding TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.Indentation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <CheckBox x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBox" IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewMultiSelectCheckBox}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                                    <Border x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayTextBorder" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsHitTestVisible="False" MinWidth="20" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Grid x:Name="ExpandCollapseChevron" Background="Transparent" Opacity="{TemplateBinding GlyphOpacity}" Padding="12,0,12,0" Width="Auto">
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding GlyphBrush}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding GlyphSize}" Height="12" Text="{TemplateBinding CollapsedGlyph}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.CollapsedGlyphVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Width="12"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding GlyphBrush}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding GlyphSize}" Height="12" Text="{TemplateBinding ExpandedGlyph}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.ExpandedGlyphVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Width="12"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TreeViewList.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <ContentThemeTransition/>
                        <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
            </TreeViewList>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TreeView.Template>
</TreeView>
```

...and the following code:

```
private void ContentPresenterGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid)sender;
    TreeViewItem parent = FindParent<TreeViewItem>(grid);
    if (parent != null)
    {
        TreeViewNode node = parent.Content as TreeViewNode;
        if (node?.HasChildren == true)
            parent.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
    }
    grid.Loaded -= ContentPresenterGrid_Loaded;
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    T parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

It procudes the following result:

[image]